# How can I find out why my Java program keeps crashing?

Tags: java, crash, java.util.scanner, do-while

I have been learning Java for a week, I have no other experiences. The program keeps crashing, I would like to be automatically asked again in the event of an incorrect entry.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean error;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        do {
            error = false;
        System.out.print("Tell me the Year: ");
        if (scan.hasNextInt()) {
            int jahr = scan.nextInt();
            scan.close();
            if (schaltjahre(jahr)) {

                System.out.println("Please enter the leap year ");
            } else {
                System.out.println("It is not a leap year");
            }

        } else {
            System.err.println("enter an integer year!");
            error = true;
            scan.close();
        }
    }while (error);
    }
   

    public static boolean schaltjahre(int jahr) {
        // Aufgabe 1
        if (jahr % 400 == 0) {
            return true;
        } else if (jahr % 100 == 0) {
            return false;
        } else if (jahr % 4 == 0) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should instantiate the scanner inside the loop and don't close it in the else statement.
Your code should be something like this :

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    boolean error;
    Scanner scan ;

    do {
        error = false;
        scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Tell me the Year: ");
        if (scan.hasNextInt()) {
            int jahr = scan.nextInt();
            scan.close();
            if (schaltjahre(jahr)) {

                System.out.println("Please enter the leap year ");
            } else {
                System.out.println("It is not a leap year");
            }

        } else {
            System.err.println("enter an integer year!");
            error = true;
        }
    } while (error);
}
```